# ASP.net MVC 3 error: CS0103

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, error-handling

I have just started to learn ASP.NET MVC 3 form [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430234040) book and I have a problem with example from it.

I always get this error

> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> **Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'Text' does not exist in the current context**

Here is the code:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(p => p.WillAttend, new[]
                                            {
                                                new SelectListItem(), Text = "Yes I'll be there", Value = bool.TrueString,
                                                new SelectListItem(), Text = "No, I can't come", Value =  bool.FalseString
                                           
                                            }, "Chose option")
```

Anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you forgot some `{}`:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(p => p.WillAttend, new[]
                                            {
                                                new SelectListItem(){ Text = "Yes I'll be there", Value = bool.TrueString},
                                                new SelectListItem(){ Text = "No, I can't come", Value =  bool.FalseString}

                                            }, "Chose option")
```